# How can I view the hierarchy of function calls when an error occurs in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, logging, visual-c++

Before working in Visual Studio, I worked in the Matlab program and there, when an error occurred, function calls were consistently displayed in the command window, indicating the line number, which part of the code caused the error. Now I work in Visual Studio and I really need the same a tool.

I found the "call hierarchy" window, but unfortunately it does not display so conveniently, since entering a function can be from different functions, it is not clear which one caused the error.

Comment: Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted. Repeated low-quality questions may result in a temporary ban from asking new questions.

Comment: You are looking for ["Call stack" window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window).

Comment: Which development environment are you using? This can help us help you better.

Comment: @PepijnKramer It's given in the tags ;)

Comment: @Fareanor Sometimes ... I just so blind ;)

Comment: I ask myself why this question has bee closed? It its (for me) completely clear and understandably fromulated. And it can and has been answered easily.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Visual Studio when you get an error you can go to Debug>Windows>Call Stack

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't Call Stack in Debug. Now I have difficulties in order to understand what needs to be done in order for this function to appear. I'm working in Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: I found Call Stack: View>Tools Panel>Settings>Commands>Context Menu>Context Menu Of The Debugger Project | Debugging>Add Command>Window>Call stack. But it didn't change anything.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I found what I was looking for: everything is as in the previous message, but Toolbar instead of Context Menu.